# I need to generate a file that consolidates all the json results of each feature execution

Tags: java, cucumber, karate, jira-xray

**I need to generate a file that consolidates all the results of each feature execution?**

karate-dsl generates the test results in a JSON file for each of the executed feature files.

[image]

Comment: I understand that you want to help others find solutions - I suggest you follow stack overflow guidelines and edit your question to be only a question and you yourself can post a separate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Thanks u @PeterThomas, oher users have asked the same for using the Jira Xray import/cucumber API. In my case, this solution is more practical. I hope they find it useful as well

Comment: upvoted. after 2 days you should be able to mark your answer as `accepted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... so I created a utility that allows me to do it in Java.

I invite you to read the README
https://github.com/jesusop/karate-cucumber-xray

The method reads all the json result files generated by karate and unifies them into a single cucumber.json file

You can aslo modify the paths of the files:

```java
private static final String JSON_DIRECTORY = "/cucumber-html-reports";
private static final String CUCUMBER_JSON = "/cucumber.json";
```

```java
private static void writeResultsToOneFile(JSONArray totalResults) throws IOException {
        File currentDirectory = new File((new File(".")).getAbsolutePath());
        String absolutePath = currentDirectory.getCanonicalPath();

        File directory = new File(absolutePath + "/" + TARGET_DIRECTORY + JSON_DIRECTORY);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }

        File cucumberJsonFile = new File(directory + CUCUMBER_JSON);
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(cucumberJsonFile)) {
            fileWriter.write(totalResults.toJSONString());

        }

        logger.info("cucumber.json file has been created at: " + cucumberJsonFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Note that upon completion of the tests, you will receive a message like this:

```
INFO: cucumber.json file has been created at: ...\karate-cucumber-xray\target\cucumber-html-reports\cucumber.json
```

Finally you can use the cucumber.json file and use it for example in the Jira Xray API.

Comment: Please do not share code via images. If the link goes south, so does the value of your answer. Please [edit] your answer by copying & pasting your code into it and wrap it into three backticks.